# WooCommerce Featured Product Code Modification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There are 2 parts to my question:

1. **Where is the featured products code in the WooCommerce plugin?** I have seen previous posts that suggest it is \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\classes\widgets\class-wc-widget-featured-products.php, but this doesn't exist in the current version 2.1. Can anyone help here?
2. By default, the featured products on the homepage a aligned LEFT. I want to edit the code to align it CENTER. It may be obvious when I can see the code, but any idea how to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for WooCommerce widget classes, it's in *\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\widgets*

It seems like featured products widget has been removed. You can use **WooCommerce Products** as the replacement with configuring it to only show featured products.

And the file for this widget is **class-wc-widget-products.php**.

You could copy this widget class and make a featured products widget yourself and modify it to be center aligned or even create an entirely different template to display the widget with `wc_get_template( 'content-widget-featured-product.php', array( 'show_rating' => $show_rating ) );` where the files are located in *\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates*

Also, don't forget to include your custom widget class if you do add another one yourself in *\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\woocommerce.php* `include_widgets()`